# Battery life: 90 min on Acer ultrabook / 12.10

Tags: 12.10, power-management, battery, acer, fan

i usually work on my Acer M5-481TG with Windows 8 x64 and recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 (x64) alongside with it.
Unfortunately, the battery-life is roughly one and a half hour - which apparently is disasterous, compared to the 5-6 hrs it runs under Windows. The whole laptop gets quite hot and the fans keep running like crazy all the time.

I though it might be the GT64M graphics card that causes this, but after checking the switcheroo-logs, the integrated solution is active (as intended).

```
root@nubuntu:~# cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1: DIS: :Pwr:0000:01:00.0
```

I've no clue what might be causing this. Besides: Neither the touchpad, nor the display-brightness-keys work properly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

try installing/looking into bumblebee, I had this issue, its running everything with the Nvidia card, but Bumblebee can control it so you use integrated graphics.

Comment: Can you provide more information, or at least a link, for Bumblebee?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've now installed Bumblebee (even though I thought PRIME would cover it already) as well as Jupiter and used the PowerTop-tweaks. However, the battery life is said to be roughly 4hrs and the fans aren't exactly silent, meaning that there must still be some power-consuming stuff running in the background. Any other suggestions?